# Optional int parameter 'movieId' is present but cannot be translated into a null value

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

**I am working on Maven multi module project so this might build error?**

I am trying to perform unit test of delete method from controller and I quite don't understand why it is happening here because methods similar to this one works.

Exception speaks for itself - cannot convert int to null. But why there is null value where it looks like curl looks correct?

```
{"timestamp":"2019-12-16T11:47:35.450+0000","path":"/movie-composite/1","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Optional int parameter 'movieId' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type."}
```

Ho mapping looks like:

```
/**
 * Sample usage: curl $HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/1
 *
 * @param movieId
 */
@ApiOperation(
        value = "${api.movie-composite.delete-composite-movie.description}",
        notes = "${api.movie-composite.delete-composite-movie.notes}")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request, invalid format of the request. See response message for more information."),
        @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable entity, input parameters caused the processing to fails. See response message for more information.")
})
@DeleteMapping(
        value = "/movie-composite/{movieId}",
        produces = "application/json")
void deleteCompositeMovie(@PathVariable int movieId);
```

its implementation:

```
@Override
public void deleteCompositeMovie(int movieId) {
    log.debug("deleteCompositeMovie will delete Movie, Reviews, Recommendations belonging to Movie with id: {}", movieId);

    movieCompositeIntegration.deleteMovie(movieId);
    movieCompositeIntegration.deleteReviews(movieId);
    movieCompositeIntegration.deleteRecommendations(movieId);

    log.debug("deleteCompositeMovie deleted Movie, Reviews, Recommendations belonging to Movie with id: {}", movieId);

}
```

And finally test that won't pass:

```
@Test
void deleteCompositeMovie() {
    int given = 1;

    deleteAndVerify(given, HttpStatus.OK);

    verify(baseMovieCompositeService, times(1)).deleteCompositeMovie(given);
}
```

where **deleteAndVerify(given, HttpStatus.OK)** looks like:

```
private void deleteAndVerify(int id, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
     webTestClient.delete()
            .uri("/movie-composite/" + id)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isEqualTo(httpStatus);
}
```

complete test file looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public class MovieCompositeServiceApplicationTests {

    public static final String FAKE_ADDRESS = "Fake address";
    public static final String FAKE_GENRE = "Fake genre";
    public static final String FAKE_TITLE = "Fake title";
    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    MovieCompositeIntegration movieCompositeIntegration;

    @MockBean
    BaseMovieCompositeService baseMovieCompositeService;

    @MockBean
    ServiceUtil serviceUtil;

    @Test
    void createMovie() {
        int movieId = 1;

        MovieAggregate movieAggregate = MovieAggregate.builder()
                .movieId(movieId)
                .genre(FAKE_GENRE)
                .title(FAKE_TITLE)
                .recommendations(getRecommendationSummaries())
                .reviews(getReviewSummaries())
                .serviceAddresses(null)
                .build();

        postAndVerify(movieAggregate);
    }

    @Test
    void getMovieById() {
        int given = 1;

        Movie movie = getMovies(given);

        Mockito.when(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress()).thenReturn("Fake service address");

        List<Recommendation> recommendations = getRecommendations(movie);
        List<Review> reviews = getReviews(movie);

        Mockito.when(movieCompositeIntegration.getMovie(given)).thenReturn(movie);
        Mockito.when(movieCompositeIntegration.getRecommendations(movie.getMovieId())).thenReturn(recommendations);
        Mockito.when(movieCompositeIntegration.getReviews(movie.getMovieId())).thenReturn(reviews);

        getAndVerifyMovie(given, HttpStatus.OK)
                .jsonPath("$.movieId").isEqualTo(given)
                .jsonPath("$.recommendations.length()").isEqualTo(3)
                .jsonPath("$.reviews.length()").isEqualTo(3);
    }

    @Test
    void getMovieByIdThrowsNotFoundException() {
        int given = 1;

        Mockito.when(movieCompositeIntegration.getMovie(given)).thenThrow(NotFoundException.class);

        getAndVerifyMovie(given, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .jsonPath("$.path").isEqualTo("/movie-composite/" + given);
    }

    @Test
    void getMovieByIdThrowsInvalidInputException() {
        int given = 1;

        Mockito.when(movieCompositeIntegration.getMovie(given)).thenThrow(InvalidInputException.class);

        getAndVerifyMovie(given, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
                .jsonPath("$.path").isEqualTo("/movie-composite/" + given);
    }

    @Test
    void deleteCompositeMovie() {
        int given = 1;

        deleteAndVerify(given, HttpStatus.OK);

        verify(baseMovieCompositeService, times(1)).deleteCompositeMovie(given);
    }

    private WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec getAndVerifyMovie(int id, HttpStatus status) {
        return webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/movie-composite/" + id)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(status)
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .expectBody();
    }

    private WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec postAndVerify(MovieAggregate movieAggregate) {
        return webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/movie-composite")
                .body(just(movieAggregate), MovieAggregate.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK)
                .expectBody();
    }

    private void deleteAndVerify(int id, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
         webTestClient.delete()
                .uri("/movie-composite/" + id)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(httpStatus);
    }

    private List<ReviewSummary> getReviewSummaries() {
        return Collections.singletonList(ReviewSummary.builder().reviewId(1).subject("s").author("a").content("c").build());
    }

    private List<RecommendationSummary> getRecommendationSummaries() {
        return Collections.singletonList(RecommendationSummary.builder().recommendationId(1).author("a").content("c").rate(1).build());
    }

    private Movie getMovies(int given) {
        return Movie.builder().movieId(given).address(FAKE_ADDRESS).genre(FAKE_GENRE).title(FAKE_TITLE).build();
    }

    private List<Review> getReviews(Movie movie) {
        return Arrays.asList(
                Review.builder().movieId(movie.getMovieId()).reviewId(1).author("Author 1").subject("Subject 1").content("Content 1").serviceAddress(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress()).build(),
                Review.builder().movieId(movie.getMovieId()).reviewId(2).author("Author 2").subject("Subject 2").content("Content 2").serviceAddress(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress()).build(),
                Review.builder().movieId(movie.getMovieId()).reviewId(3).author("Author 2").subject("Subject 3").content("Content 3").serviceAddress(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress()).build()
        );
    }

    private List<Recommendation> getRecommendations(Movie movie) {
        return Arrays.asList(
                Recommendation.builder().movieId(movie.getMovieId()).recommendationId(1).author("Author 1").rate(1).content("Content 1").serviceAddress(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress()).build(),
                Recommendation.builder().movieId(movie.getMovieId()).recommendationId(2).author("Author 2").rate(2).content("Content 2").serviceAddress(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress()).build(),
                Recommendation.builder().movieId(movie.getMovieId()).recommendationId(3).author("Author 3").rate(3).content("Content 3").serviceAddress(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress()).build()
        );
    }

}
```

Why it won't pass where **getMovieById()** looks very similar when it comes to input and url and it passes?

Comment: Can you convert this into an [mre] that produces the same error message?

Comment: Hi @second, thank you for response. Actually this wouldn't make sense because as you see everything looks correct, but here it is more about some build error in maven multi module project.  Here is link to complete project https://github.com/geborskimateusz/movie-rest-services  where all code related to this error is located under com.geborskimateusz.microservices.composite.movie and com.geborskimateusz.api.composite.movie

Comment: Also why controller receives null when value is already present in path? "/movie-composite/" + id

Comment: After setting up your project and running the test I do not receive an error. As far as I understand your comment there shoulnd't be a difference to the example from your question?